# Why is $RrR$ an ideal (specifically why is it closed under addition)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Context: Exercise 14, Section 3.2 of Hungerford’s Abstract Algebra.

**Definition:** An ideal $P$ in a ring $R$ is said to be prime if $P\neq R$ and for any ideals $A,B$ in $R$
$$AB \subseteq P \implies A\subseteq P \text{ or } B\subseteq P$$

---

> If $P$ is an ideal in a not necessarily commutative ring $R$, then the following conditions are equivalent.
>
> (a) P is a prime ideal.
>
> (b) If $r,s\in R$ are such that $rRs\subseteq P$, then $r \in P$ or $s \in P$. [Hint: If $(a)$ holds and $rRs\subseteq P$, then $(RrR)(RsR)\subseteq P$, whence $RrR\subseteq P$ or $RsR\subseteq P$, say $RrR\subseteq P$. If $A= (r)$, then $A^3\subseteq RrR \subseteq P$, whence $r\in A\subseteq P$.]
>
> (c) If $(r)$ and $(s)$ are principal ideals of $R$ such that $(r)(s)\subseteq P$, then $r\in P$ or $s\in P$.
>
> (d) If $U$ and $V$ are right ideals in $R$ such that $UV\subseteq P$, then $U\subseteq P$ or $V\subseteq P$.
>
> (e) If $U$ and $V$ are left ideals in $R$ such that $UV\subseteq P$, then $U\subseteq P$ or $V\subseteq P$.

There are several way to prove this exercise, for instance $(a)\Rightarrow (b)\Rightarrow (c) \Rightarrow (d) \Rightarrow (e) \Rightarrow (a)$ and $(a)\Leftrightarrow (b) \Leftrightarrow (c) \Leftrightarrow (d) \Leftrightarrow (e)$, former is the least number of implication needed to prove above exercise. But I don’t think it is the most easiest way to do it.

I want to prove this exercise by showing following implications (which I think is the easiest approach): $(a) \Leftrightarrow (c)$ and $(a) \Rightarrow (b) \Rightarrow (d) \Rightarrow (a)$. I am not considering $(e)$, because $(d)$ can be replaced by $(e)$ with slight modification.

[Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2161688/861687) of $(a) \Leftrightarrow (c)$is fairly easy. Proof of $(b)\Rightarrow (d)$ is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4718299/861687) (below $\neg a\implies \neg b$). Proof of $(d)\Rightarrow (a)$ is trivial. So only thing left to show is that $(a)\Rightarrow (b)$. Though given hint is quite straightforward. I am having hard time showing $RrR$ is an ideal, to be specific $RrR$ is closed under addition. Let $arb, crd\in RrR$. **How to show $arb+crd=xry$ for some $x,y\in R$?** I tryed using $x=a+c$ and $y=b+d$. But this don’t work. $RrR$ is closed under addition is also used in filling details of $A^3\subseteq RrR$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3616385/861687)).

Comment: It is by the very definition of $RrR$, see the penultimate point on [WP Ideal page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory)#Examples_and_properties) and the one before it. In Hungerford, see Theorem 2.5 (ii).

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist Yaa I missed that.

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist I don’t think that Theorem 2.5 ii is real enough since it assumes that the ring is equipped with identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint：
Can you prove that for left ideals $A_1,A_2,\dots ,A_n$ , $A_1A_2\dots A_n$ is still a left ideal?

Comment: Yes. Since $Rr$ and $R$ are left ideal, $RrR=(Rr)R$ is also left ideal. Since $rR$ and $R$ are right ideal, $RrR=R(rR)$ is also left ideal. Therefore $RrR$ is an ideal. Thank you for the answer.